# How to improve speed of opencv fastNlMeansDenoising method?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I am using opencv fastNlMeansDenoising for very small dot noise present in B&W image.But It is taking more time(5 to 8 sec) to process an image(3306*4676).

```
public static BufferedImage despecklEffect(BufferedImage source){
System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME ); 
Mat sourceImage=ImageProc.img2Mat(source);
Photo.fastNlMeansDenoising(sourceImage, sourceImage,50,7,21); 
return ImageProc.mat2Img(sourceImage); }
```

Comment: How can i speed up this method by changing parameter ?

Comment: The searchWindowSize parameter is affecting your performance linearly. So changing the value from 21 to e.g. 13 will speed up performance, but will also reduce the quality of your result.